# Looking to develop a visual odometer (distance traveled) APP for indoor use

Tags: computer-vision

Are there any open source code which will take a video taken indoors (from a smart phone for example of a home or office buildings, hallways) and superimpose that on a 2D picture showing the path traveled? This can be a handr drawn picture or a photo of a floor layout.

First I thought of doing this using the accelerometer and compass sensors but thought that perhaps one can get better accuracy with the visual odometer approach. I only need 0.5 to 1 meter accuracy. The phone will also collect important information indoors (no gps) for superimposing that data on the path traveled (this is the real application of this project and we know how to do this part). The post processing of the video can be done later on a stand alone computer so speed and cpu power is not a issue.

Challenges - 
The user will simply hand carry the smart phone so the video taker is moving (walking) and not fixed
limit the video rate to keep the file size small (5 frames/sec? is that ok?). Typically need perhaps a full hour of video

Will using inputs from the phone sensors help the visual approach?

any help or guidance is appreciated Thanks

Comment: BTW Code can also be licensed

Comment: Are you looking for something that does this? Or do you want to develop something that does this, and are you looking for samples and/or a starting point for your research?

Comment: If already available then I can use or license if not then developing it is a option also.

Comment: If you have samples would be great and yes perhaps a starting point of semilar work performed if available.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked in the area for quite some time. There are three points which I'd care to make.

**Vision only is hard**

Vision based navigation using just a cellphone camera is very difficult. Most of the literature with great results show ~1% distance traveled as state-of-the-art but is usually using stereo cameras. Stereo helps a great deal, particularly in indoor environments for coping with scale drift. I've worked on a system which achieves 0.5% distance traveled for stereo but only roughly 5% distance traveled for monocular. While I can't share code, much of our system was inspired by this [Sibley and Mei paper](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~cmei/articles/AConstantTimeEfficientStereoSLAMSystem_mei_bmvc_09.pdf).

Stereo code in our case ran at full 60fps on a desktop. Provided you can push data fast enough, it'll be fine. With your error envelope, you can only navigate for 100m or so. Is that enough?

**Multi-sensor is way to go. Though other sensors are worse than vision by themselves.**

I've heard some good work with accelerometers mounted on the foot to do ZUPT (zero velocity updates) when the foot is briefly motionless on the ground while taking a step in order to zero out drift. This approach has the clear drawback of needing to mount the device on your foot, making a vision approach largely useless.

Compass is interesting but will be distracted by the ton of metal within an office building. Translating few feet around a large metal cabinet might cause 50+ degrees of directional jump.

Ultimately, a combination of sensors is likely to be the best if you can make that work.

**Can you solve a simpler problem?**

How much control do you have over your environment? Can you slap down fiducial markers? Can you do wifi triangulation? Does it need to be an initial exploration? If you can go through the environment before hand and produce visual bubbles (akin to Google Street View) to match against, you'll be much more accurate.

Comment: Thanks, Actually 100 m is good enough. As for the "simpler problem" all are good sudgestions but would not be an option.  If you think your monocular approach can work let's say 50-100m runs with 60fps video taken can be acheived (i.e. provide a distance traveled over a 2D floor layout from video) perhaps I can send you some video of hallways along with a floor layout for example and you can send me some distance traveled paths and we can talk about licensing such a system for some applications we have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any software that does this directly (though it might exist) but stuff similar to what you want to do has been done. A few pointers:

- Google for ["Vision based robot localization"](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&client=ubuntu&hs=mUN&channel=cs&q=vision%20based%20robot%20localization&oq=vision%20based%20robot%20localization&aq=f&aqi=&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=42984l46160l0l15l12l0l0l0l2l200l1286l6.5.1l12) the problem you state is very similar to the problem robots with a camera have when they enter a new environment. In this field the approach is usually to have the robot map its environment and then use the model for later reference, but the techniques are similar to what you'll need.
- [Optical flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) will roughly tell you in what direction the camera is moving, but it won't tell you the speed because you have no objective reference. This is because you don't know if the things you see moving in the video feed are 1cm away and very small or 1 mile away and very big.
- If you know the [camera matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix) of the camera recording the images you could try [partial 3D scene reconstruction](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&client=ubuntu&hs=L02&channel=cs&q=partial%203D%20scene%20reconstruction&oq=partial%203D%20scene%20reconstruction&aq=f&aqi=&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=18592l18882l0l2l2l0l0l0l0l116l193l1.1l2) techniques to take a stab at the speed. Note that you can do the 3D scene stuff without the camera matrix (this is the "uncalibrated" part you see in the title of a lot of the google results), the camera matrix will let you add real world object sizes (and hence distances) to your reconstruction.
- The amount of images/second you need depends on the speed of the camera. More is better, but my guess is that 5/second should be sufficient at walking speeds.
- Using extra sensors will help. Probably the robot localization articles talk about this as well.